# Error: initscripts conflicts with 1:redhat-release-server-6Server-6.10.0.12.0.1.el6.x86_64

Tags: centos7

When I try to install oracle using the following command,

```
sudo yum install oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall -y
```

I got the following error.

```
Error: initscripts conflicts with 1:redhat-release-server-6Server-6.10.0.12.0.1.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The OS version is as follow.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

and initscript version is

```
$ rpm -qa | grep initscripts
initscripts-9.49.46-1.el7.x86_64
```

Could anyone let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks
Shuja

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have multiple repos enabled.

Step1:
Check your repos and share output here.

Command:

```
yum repolist
```

or

Command:

```
yum repolist --disablerepo=epel
```

the command will return multiple repos.

Install a utility called YUM Utilis

Command:

```
yum install -y yum-utils
```

or

Command:

```
yum install -y yum-utils --disablerepo=epel
```

then Disable the repos from below command...
Commands:

```
yum-config-manager --disable reponame
yum-config-manager --disable reponame2
```

For an example I have disabled these 2 repos in my box

```
yum-config-manager --disable ol6_UEK_latest
yum-config-manager --disable ol6_latest
```

now after disabling the unwanted EPEL6 or OL6 repos, you may only see the RHEL 7 repo.

try it and confirm.